# Postgresql Leftover Connections (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

This is how I try to start and terminate a postgresql connection with ruby on rails.(heroku)

```
conn = PGconn.connect("blablabla", 5432, '', '', "blablabla", "blablabla", "blablabla")
res  = conn.exec('SELECT last_name FROM employees')
hey = conn.close()
```

Before I added conn.close(), I had connections stack over and basically crash the server(max 20 connections were allowed by heroku).

Now that I added conn.close(), it is significantly better however I still have 1 or 2 connections remain(even after the browser is closed) time to time. (Sometimes this error does not happen.)

Any ideas from experienced users ? (Literally started ruby on rails a week ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the rails process starts up it will acquire a database connection and keep it open until the rails process ends.

Typically in rails you don't manage your database connection, instead you create model objects that map to your database tables and manipulate those instead of using sql. If you do want to use a database connection manually, it might make sense to acquire it from ActiveRecord::Base, i.e.

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
last_names = connection.execute('SELECT last_name FROM employees')
```

read more about active record: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html